# Bending timespace fabric model: does it explain gravity by another gravity?

Tags: general-relativity

In the Einstein's model of time-space bending, in the simplified version, the fabric of the Universe is in 2D, while the planets are in 3D. This is the first inconsistency that I think ruins the explanation of the model. You can't arbitrarily dimensionaly downsize one part and not the other, you get a dimensionaly inconsistent model. But that's the less problematic part.

The real problem for me to understand is the following: if a heavy planet bends the cloth and creates a slope... this means that there is another vertical gravitational field that pushes the planet down into the fabric in order to bend it. Furthermore, the light object (a satellite for example) then falls onto the heavy object, meaning it's going down the slope. In order to have something react to a slope, you need to have a vertical down-pulling field. This all means that we're explaining gravity by another (vertical) gravity, without which the whole metaphor just doesn't work.

I'm not saying Einstein was wrong. I'm just saying that I have a serious problem understanding this model, firstly because it's half 2D and half 3D, and secondly, more importantly, because it presumes another gravity through the entire metaphorical universe. Since all physicians in the world agree with Einstein's idea I presume it's accurate, but this model of explanation, if you ask me, fails heavily. Can anyone please help me understand the model?

Comment: Einstein’s GR has nothing to do with 2D cloth. That is just a misleading popularization that has confused several billion people.

Comment: @G.Smith several billion plus one

Comment: @David Z (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/124/david-z) thanx for pointing me to these questions, I somehow haven't been able to find them through search.